# Creating a function that names objects created based on a function in R

Tags: r, function, naming

I have a question about creating a function that creates ggplots. I want to create my own function to graph values in multiple data frames quickly instead of writing a whole ggplot with each argument filled out each time. What I want to do is to input a vector of the names of the data frames, have the function create the graphs and have each saved as a new object with a different name. Example of my idea is…

```
myfunction <- function(x) {
              ggplot(x, aes(x = time, y = result)) +
                           geom_point()
}
```

I want to be able to do something like

```
myfunction(c(testtype1, testtype2, testtype3))
```

and have the function create objects plot1, plot2, plot3. As of now, I can only do

```
plot1 <- myfunction(testtype1)
plot2 <- myfunction(testtype2)
plot3 <- myfunction (testtype3)
```

I don’t want to keep typing that over and over, especially if I have a lot of test types. Is there a way that the function can be modified to use the function to name the objects according to some formula?

Comment: maybe `lapply(list(testtype1, testtype2, testtype3), myfunction)`

Comment: See the answer below, let me know if that works and you'd like bit more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

With this, you can provide any number of (appropriate) data frames, and the `l_my_fun` would return a list containing the plots.

```
l_my_fun <- function(x, ...) {
  l <- list(x, ...)
  ps <- lapply(l, myfunction)
  ps
}

out <- l_my_fun(testtype1, testtype2, testtype3)
```

For example, now access the second plot as

```
out[[2]]
```

[image]